# How to supply a 'const char*' argument for a function that takes a 'char*' in C++?

Tags: c++, function, arguments, constants

I have the following code.

```
const char* my_input = "my string";

void my_function(char* my_argument);

int main()
{
  my_function(my_input);
}

void my_function(char* my_argument)
{
  /* Do something */
}
```

Notice that the argument for my_function expects a 'char*', but I supply it with a 'const char*'.

My IDE gives me the error: No matching function for call 'my_function'.

I assume it is because the function call is being interpreted as 'my_function(const char* my_argument)', which I have clearly not defined (and do not want to).

How do I can I make it so that my constant input is valid for an expected non-constant argument?

In my real program, I have a function that takes in a 'char*', however it does NOT modify it. The argument itself might not be a constant (and isn't usually), however sometimes I expect a constant.

Comment: looks like we have an anonymous answer-downvoting robot here again

Comment: Does the function attempt to modify the data? This is the first question you have to answer.

Comment: @AnT -- No, I have no intent to modify the argument.

Comment: @M.M -- What do you mean?

Comment: @SirJony a few questions in a row I checked, all the answers (or all but one) had been downvoted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not being interpreted as `my_function(const char *)` call. It is being interpreted as `my_function(char *)` call, since there's no other versions of `my_function` available anywhere. However, this is not allowed because it violates the rules of const-correctness of C++ language. These rules prohibit implicit conversion of `const char *` pointer to `char *` type.

The first question you have to answer here is why you are trying to pass a pointer to *constant* data to a function that potentially treats it as *non-constant* (modifiable) data. This is an obvious violation of const-correctness.

If your `my_function` does not really modify the data, then the next question is why it is declared with `char *` parameter instead of `const char *` parameter.

And only as the last resort, if you are sure that `my_function` does not really modify the data, but for some reason cannot change its declaration (e.g. third party code), you can work around this problem by forcing the conversion to `char *` type

```
my_function(const_cast<char *>(my_input));
```

Comment: So, in my real program, I have a 'const char* empty_string = "";'. And sometimes I want to use it as an argument. Does this violate const-correctness? If so, how do I go about fixing it with the same intent?

Comment: @Sir Jony: Your `empty_string` is a pointer to a string literal. String literals are immutable. If you pass it to a modifying function as `char *`, not only will this violate const-correctness, your program will actually crash and burn. You are not providing important details about the situation, which is why it is impossible to give you a specific answer.

Comment: @Sir Jony: If you do not modify the data in the function (as you state in the last part of your question), then, as I stated above, you should simply declare your function with `const char *` parameter.

Comment: Thank you! I think I got that problem fixed, but now I have a linking issue to fix (probably not as a result of your solution). :)

Comment: A well described answer. I just learned my new idea for the day +1

Answer (score 4):

Here, the stablest solution would be to make your input a `char*` rather than a `const char*`:

```
char my_input[] = "my string";
```

However, if you cannot, another solution would be to use `const_cast` to "reassure" your IDE on the parameter:

```
int main()
{
    my_function(const_cast<char*>(my_input));
}
```

But be careful with this kind of tricks: if your variable is read-only and your function `my_function` try to modify it, be ready for a segmentation fault.

You can do that if you are certain your C function won't try to do anything but read the pointer's data, even if the argument is not `const`, as it happens sometimes in C libraries.
Else, you have to find a way to pass a modifiable parameter.

If your data is `const`, a more heavy but secure way would be to copy your original pointer into a new one, modifiable one:

```
int main()
{
    char* copy = strdup(my_input); // Or a static buffer if you know precisely your input size
    my_function(copy);
    free(copy);
}
```

Comment: Is there a solution without "hacking" and possibly introducing more problems?

Comment: @SirJony it's not "hacking". C++ compiler prevents you from doing some basic stupid things, and to override it you have to be verbose.

Comment: @AntonSavin, OK. As long as it's not a runtime issue, I'm fine. I was just worried that the compiler won't warn me. But if it does, I guess it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `const_cast`:

```
my_function(const_cast<char*>(my_input));
```

However, this is dangerous, because if `my_function` modifies `my_argument`, it is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, a const variable cannot be modified, so you cannot pass it to a function that may change its value.

If you need to pass the value of that variable, then the best way to do it is creating a writable non-const copy.

```
char my_copy[strlen(my_input) + 1];
strcpy(my_copy, my_input);
my_function(my_copy);
```